# Getting back the old Alt-Tab windows switching behavior in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

When you run more than six applications on Windows 7 and you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, icons representing the first six applications and the desktop appear on the first row of the grid and you can cycle with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>... through the six most-recently used windows the usual way, but the seventh and other less recently used windows don't follow the same rules.

Instead they get grouped together according to their application, but disregarding whether they were recently used or not. This new behavior is mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080701-00/?p=21793).

I am very used to the old way of cycling and the new system is driving me crazy. I tend to have 20 or so windows open at one time and I frequently need to alt-tab to the seventh or eighth window on the stack, but it doesn't work the same any more.

How do I put back the old behavior, so that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ... goes through the whole list in most-recent to least-recent order?

Comment: Question is quite old now. But let me know if 1. Holding alt (any) and pressing tab - tab -tab ... and 2. alt + shift + [tab tab tab] (for backwards) work today with your machine. I am curious.

Comment: Under System properties > Advanced > Performance options > Visual effects, I had adjusted for best performance
I was getting grid of icons which is classic ALT+TAB behavior. So, I was curious.

Comment: Let me know if that is not the classic grid. I think it is. Another thing, even then, 'Always on Top' applications get a special treatment.

Comment: I *think* the broken link in the OP is moved to: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080701-00/?p=21793

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To restore the Windows XP Alt-Tab functionality simply launch regedit, add a **DWORD** named **`AltTabSettings`** to **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`** and set its value to **`1`**.

And here's a one-line PowerShell script which does the above:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer AltTabSettings ([int]1)
```

Comment: +1: Tested here, works like a charm without a reboot, nice one.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, accepted. Is there a way to turn off the weird W7 ordering without turning off the nice W7 large alt-Tab preview icons etc? That is, can I keep the W7 alt-tab interface but with the XP ordering?

Comment: worked here too, can't take the default behavior its not functional at all..

Comment: Thanks. But why this happens? Why explorer forget to switch windows with `Alt`+`Tab`?

Comment: @Isaac it happens due to change they wanted it to work, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx

Comment: Paste `reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v AltTabSettings /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f` into the "Run" dialog if you're too lazy to use PowerShell like me.

Comment: Superb - cheers.

Comment: Not working. Do I need to do a restart?

Comment: I'm getting the "old" ui but it's still ordering it in the new way

Comment: best and easiest way, works also for Windows 10 easy:
https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: In the current version of Windows 10, yes, this does appear to require a [restart of Windows Explorer](https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/restart-windows-explorer/); rebooting the entire machine also works.

Answer (score 48):

Not sure about tab order but you can access the old Windows XP looking Alt-Tab like this:

1. Hold down the left alt key
2. Press and release the right alt key, keeping the left alt key held down
3. Then, still keeping the left alt key held down, tab-tab-tab away to you heart's content...

[image]

Thanks to [BlogSofts](http://blogsofts.com/windows-7-easter-egg-shows-the-xp-alt-tab-prompt/) via [The Road To Know Where](http://bhandler.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!70F64BC910C9F7F3!7645.entry)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know it could do that! But it's a PITA that you have to hit the right Alt then the left Alt for this to work.

Comment: You do get used to it after a while :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this the default behavior? I like that sooooo much better.

Comment: Add the "AltTabSettings" DWORD = 1 in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" then it'll become the default behavior.

Comment: AMAZING! 

@Hondalex : also it makes it so you can't map this (in addition to the newer alt+tab) using the Steam Controller (without AHK magic at least)

Answer (score 32):

While I tried, liked and upvoted the accepted answer I found this setting by googling a bit more:
*[Windows 7: bring back old Alt+Tab behavior, turn off Aero Peek](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503121134/http://blog.grushin.com/2009/12/04/windows-7-bring-back-old-alttab-behavior-turn-off-aero-peek)*

1. Go to System Properties (right click Computer in an explorer window and choose properties)
2. Click Advanced System Settings in the left panel
3. You should be on the Advanced Tab, in the performance section, click Settings
4. Uncheck Enable Aero Peek

It turns out you can keep the Windows 7 look, but avoid the odd flashing behaviour (lack of better words) that is Aero Peek.

Comment: Great tip! but I can't up-vote you because your answer doesn't seem to answer the original posters question.

Comment: I'm upvoting yours b/c you have added another piece to the puzzle of "making alt-tab work like it used to." Thanks - great nugget!

Comment: This answer works best if you can't edit your registry directly (perhaps on a locked down machine)

Comment: link doesn't work any more => always post the important piece from the remote site

Comment: @sjngm Thank you for notifying me. I copied the steps from the link and edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see "Enable Aero Peek" here. Windows 7 Pro SP1. Link to image below.

(Beware of autoplay videos with sound below. This uploading site has gone to hell. I would have uploaded the image directly to the forum if I'm allowed, or knew how.)
http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f177/DontMessAroundWithBill/enabaero.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The so called Aero Peek is not usable at all when the "alt-tab" window overlaps with current window. I am so glad it's sensible now.

Answer (score 6):

Try the combination <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It uses the Aero interface, but give you a full cycle of your applications.

Comment: Interesting, I always hated the Win + Tab switcher but it does seem to keep stack ordering so maybe I'll have to start giving it a try once again.

Comment: @jpierson **wow** I never used it long enough to notice that. That's actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

In have just installed Windows 10 version 20H2. In addition to the registry key, you need to go to the settings (Windows + i) > System > Multitasking and set "Alt + tab" to the only setting not containing any "Edge" (in German Windows: "Nur Fenster öffnen", in English should be something like: "Open windows only"). Wrong German translation, BTW! Should be "Nur offene Fenster". ;-)