# Make minimized window move to the end of the alt-tab list

Tags: windows-7

In XP, if you minimize the current window, it goes to the end of the list for <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> purposes.  In Windows 7, if I minimize a window and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I go right back to that window I was trying to get rid of.

Is there a way to make minimize push the window to the end of the list, or some other way to manage the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> list order?

**Edit:**  I apologize for saying that this is how Windows 7 behaves.  It turns out that Windows 7 *sometimes* gets into a state where Minimize does not put the window at the bottom of the z-order.  I cannot figure out exactly what steps cause Windows 7 to get into this state, but I must do it pretty frequently because this bugs me all the time.

So, when Windows 7 is in this state, here is what happens:

1. Open multiple windows.  I usually have them all maximized.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Call this window "A".
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Call this window "B".
4. Minimize window "B".  Window "A" is now visible.
5. Press Alt-Tab.

At this point, I see window "B" again, even though it should have been at the back of the Alt-Tab list (or Z-ordering as it's called).

When Windows 7 behaves this way, I've tried adding the `AltTabSettings` registry entry.  This changes the appearance of the Alt-Tab dialog, but doesn't change the Z-ordering effect of the Minimize button.

When I just now tried to reproduce this, Minimize works properly (pushes window to end of Z-order).  I haven't yet been able to pinpoint what changes this behavior.

Comment: Status no-repro.

Comment: @NGLN, you're saying that when you minimize a window in Windows 7, it goes to the end of the Alt-Tab list?

Comment: This drives me mad too! Most of the time minimizing the window puts it at the end of the list, but at some point while I'm using the PC that changes and minimizing it leaves it at the beginning of the list. It's the inconsistency that really annoys me.

Comment: Comments on the article @lightinthedark linked to ( http://superuser.com/a/766448/244608 ) suggest that the behaviour may be dependent on how many windows are open. (:sigh: Oh, Microsoft.) Unfortunately, no one mentioned whether or not that number is adjustable (e.g. in the registry) or hardcoded. I suspect the latter, but if anyone finds anything to the contrary, I'd love to know.

Comment: As an aside, the same behaviour could sometimes be observed in Win XP, too.  As far as I could tell, it tended to sometimes (but not always) start happening when there were too many windows open (typically more than could fit in the Alt-Tab pane, so around 22+), and stopped once enough windows were closed.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of minimizing, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>.  This will put the window at the bottom of the Z-order.

Comment: But without minimizing it. It'd be nice to be able to do both.

Comment: This is quite beside the point, and does not work.  The window only goes to the next in the queue, not last.  Plust this does not minimise the window, either.

Comment: This does NOT work.

Comment: @NZDev, it used to.  I assume you tried in Windows 10.  It worked in Windows 7.

Comment: In windows 10 it does not work because it does not adhere to the Z-Order, It would seem.

The below answer adjusting the Registry works, but it removes the visual Tiles of Windows 10 Alt Tab.

Alt-Esc does minimise and does put to the bottom of the order.

Cheers.  

I wish I could have best of both worlds???

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK- it's not the bottom of the Z-order, unless I'm missing something.

When you do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the window you <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>-aped comes right back.

Comment: The Alt-Esc is working for me (moves the window to the end of the Alt-Tab list).

Comment: And now it's not working for me any more ... ¯\\_ (ツ)_/¯ (note: I was and am using Win10)

Answer (score 4):

From a similar question [Getting back the old alt-tab windows switching behavior in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/114001/getting-back-the-old-alt-tab-windows-switching-behavior-in-windows-7):

> To restore the XP Alt-Tab functionality simply, lauch regedit, add a DWORD named **AltTabSettings** to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer** and set its value to 1.

You need to restart Explorer for changes to take effect (restarting your computer is an easy way to do this)

Personally I prefer the 3D Aero flip (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) which (on my system at least) pushes minimised apps to the back of the stack

Comment: ? The WindowsKey+Tab doesn't push minimized apps to the back of the stack for me. It behaves in the exact same way as when I press Alt+Tab (with the only exception that it select the currently focused window first)

Comment: Are you using Windows 7? As far as I know I have no add-ons or tweaks that would change this behaviour.

Comment: Yes. Windows 7 Professional 32-bit. I don't have any add-ons or tweaks either AFAIK...

Comment: Strange - I would be interested to know what other peoples' experiences are. As far as I can tell, the registry tweak I posted should work though.

Comment: This changes the Alt-Tab dialog.  It does not change the Minimize behavior.  Someone else posted the same thing and then deleted it when they realized it was wrong.  Please leave up this answer for others to see, since it's pretty common advice on the web, but unhelpful in this question.

Comment: @JeremyStein: Thanks for the downvote. I can't seem to replicate the problem you are having. When I minimize a window, it goes to the right-hand side of the ALT-TAB dialog and the bottom of the Aero 3D Flip stack. Perhaps you have not explained it clearly.

Comment: @JeremyStein: BTW did you actually try the Alt-Tab fix? A lot of people have reported success, e.g. http://www.yancylent.com/2010/03/11/windows-7-alt-tab-order/

Comment: @James, I updated the question with additional information.  It doesn't look like the person in the link you posted above had the minimize issue I described.  Clearly it fixed whatever Alt-Tab issue they had, but it seems unrelated to the Z-order of minimized windows.

Comment: @JeremyStein: so you can confirm the issue definitely still occurs with the registry tweak?

Comment: @James, Yes, I still have this issue with the registry tweak.

Comment: OK this works a treat in Windows 10.
It changes the tile view of alt tab and uyou no longer get a picture of the window, you now get icons, but it puts the minimised window to the back.

I wonder if we can have both window view and minimise going to the back.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a way to change the Z-order of a specific window (other than the method that Jeremy suggested) but you can cycle through the list in reverse order if all you wish to do is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through the rest of the windows:

1. Minimize the window
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. If you continue to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, you can cycle through the list in reverse order by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>

If you follow these steps, the window that you just minimized should appear last in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list order.

Comment: As an addendum, note that this follows normal keyboard tab switching behaviour, as long as you keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button held down.  If you release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then it goes back to iterating in normal order.  (Or vice versa, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while iterating in normal order lets you go in reverse instead.)

Comment: This is not what I would want to do. If I minimize a window, I'd like it to go to the back of my queue, and be able to get to my next most recently used app with a single alt-tab.

Answer (score 1):

It would surprise me a lot if there was a way to force Windows to change the way it does alt-tab.
The only tweaks I know of have to do with the look of the alt-tab window, rather than with
its algorithms.

You might instead be interested in one of the following two alt-tab replacements,
which might better suite your working habits :

[**VistaSwitcher**](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html)

[image: image1]

[**Switcher**](http://insentient.net/index.html)

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx) article explains what's going on and why sometimes a minimised goes to the back, and sometimes not.

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you have to go into the comments to get the real story. It seems that whether minimize/z-order behaviour is correct (i.e. what the OP wants) is dependent on the *number of windows open*. The hell? I wonder if that number is hardcoded somewhere, or is read from the registry...

Comment: Link 403s, here's it on the web archive with the aforementioned comments: http://web.archive.org/web/20100905092558/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx