# How can I send a window to the end of the Alt-Tab list in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, alt-tab

Up until upgrading to Windows 8, I would use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to make a window go to the end of the Alt-Tab list, and "get out of the way." For example, if my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list looks like:

> A  B  C  D  E

With A as the active window, hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will make it into:

> B  C  D  E  A

With B active, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing once will end with window C:

> C  B  D  E  A

Ever since I got Windows 8, this isn't working any more –– hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> hides the active window, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will get it right back.

Why is that? Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: I found many a similar questions dated to the move from XP to Windows 7, but nothing from recent years.

Comment: For many reasons, I find that "upgrading to Windows 8" is really downgrading the user experience. Your example is not the only one.

Comment: 7.5 years later, but I found an interesting clue:
It's possible to use the Windows 3.11 style switcher by [holding alt, tapping the other alt, and hitting tab](https://superuser.com/a/114047).
This old switcher is using the old ordering, so alt-esc sends things to the end of the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [Alt-Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab) :

> When the Alt+Tab task switcher window is not active, Alt+Esc places
>   the active window at the bottom of the Z-order. In Windows 8 the
>   behavior has changed, the window will be moved level down the Z-order
>   instead of going to the end.

If you want Windows 8's Alt-Esc to work as it used to work in Windows 7,
the answer is negative - there is no information whether this is possible.
Maybe in the future something will come up, but not now.

If you don't need a touch screen and you want your computer to behave like it did in
Windows 7, the only solution is to go back to Windows 7.

Comment: It looks like the Win32 API function [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be able to do this. I'll see if I can do something with that when I get a bit of time (maybe tomorrow). (cc @aviv)

Comment: The Windows API for doing that certainly still exists, the problem is that the Alt+Tab switcher does not use it. Writing your own extension that will hook Alt+Tab and do it your way will surely work. Your best tool may be [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), using the [DllCall](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm) command.

Comment: Are you saying the task switcher keeps its own independent list of windows?

Comment: I am saying that it has its own way of calling SetWindowPos that evidently is not what you want. Remark: In Autohotkey it is much easier to use the [WinSet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm) command, rather than DllCall.

Comment: I was talking about intercepting `Alt` + `Esc` to set the window as bottommost. This is, as far as I know, a systemwide list. My testing so far (C#) has somehow led to the window being placed as the first item in the task switcher... (if WinSet works, perhaps you can amend your answer? I will continue with what I am currently trying, for now.)

Comment: A bit more testing, and it seems that `SetWindowPos` itself has changed as of Windows 8 - I get the expected behaviour on Windows 7. Good job, Microsoft, you broke it.

Comment: Implementing that behavior for Alt-Esc is a one-liner with Autohotkey.

Comment: Unfortunately, while it is a one-liner, it does not work as expected. As I said in my previous comment, `SetWindowPos` itself appears to have changed (from your answer, I assumed it was just the `Alt` + `Esc` hotkey, not the underlying API - I was mistaken). I just tried with AHK/WinSet, and the results are exactly the same as manually calling the API function. I consider this broken, as `HWND_BOTTOM` no longer places the window at the bottom... I'm going to give up for now.

Comment: You might raise this up in the Autohotkey forums. Some developer might find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This app does the job and is a little configurable:

[vistaswitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html)

I would like to speak with the Microsoft genius who decided to eliminate the ALT+ESC functionality.