# Alt+tab: How do I get the desktop to behave the same way as other windows?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, alt-tab

It is not uncommon for me to switch between my desktop and a single window rapidly (don't ask :p), and I always use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between two windows. However, for some reason, the desktop is always last in line of all my windows when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tabbing</kbd>, making it impossible to switch to the desktop as easily as to other windows whenever I have multiple windows open.

This is driving me crazy. Is there any way to make the desktop behave the same way as the other windows when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> between them? I just want to be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back and forth easily. I'm using Windows 8.

Ps, I know that there are other ways to quickly go to the desktop, but <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> takes time and effort each time. Taking my time to post on a forum is *obviously* a much better use of my time ;)

Comment: I think alt+shift+tab will switch to the last window on the list (desktop? I don't use Windows so can't test if it works) but if win+d takes too much time I'm not sure this is a solution.

Comment: alt+shift+tab switches between tabs, such as within your browser. If it were indiscriminate, then it would have been a decent solution. I really just don't want to do something different to get to the desktop than to get to any other window. I could get used to using a different shortcut.

Comment: I thought switching tabs used ctrl+tab?

Comment: I think you have the answer to this at http://superuser.com/a/114058/26328. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Alt+tab on XP doesn't have the desktop in its list at all. And I just screwed up: alt+shift+tab is the reverse of alt+tab, always selecting the desktop first and when the desktop is already on, it automatically opens the last-maximized window. I guess that works...

Comment: Or not - I'm not really sure how alt+shift+tab works. It almost seems like it picks a window at random to maximize. I'm trying it out some more right now.

Comment: How does Windows key + D "take time"? It seems like you have a solution, I can't understand why it's not suitable

Comment: Well, I often do the following: alt+tab .. alt+tab ... alt+tab, and so on. I keep my fingers on those keys. windows key and D are awkwardly positioned compared, so it takes a bit of effort to get to, and forces me to move my entire hand each time. It seems so odd that there isn't a simple way to move between the desktop and a window without having to change your hand's position, but alright then, I guess not...

Comment: AS @Trengot suggests, using Shift+Alt+Tab repeatedly switches between the current Window and the desktop and back. So one extra key (Shift).

Comment: Use your thumb to switch between Alt and Win and your index finger for D/ring finger for tab. No movement of the whole hand necessary. If your proportions/number of fingers doesn't allow for that it would work, sorry. In addition think about your workflow, you might be able to improve it by switching something up.