# Keep screen static when cycling through open apps in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, when you cycle through opened apps using `Alt + Tab` key the background also keeps switching according to the app you are cycling through. For example you have opened Paint, Word, Calculator and PDF and you are currently working in Word file. Now you want to open Paint so you use `Alt + Tab`. It is working but the problem is background also keeps changing when you cycle through the apps. I want that to be static means if I'm on Word when I start cycling through apps then background should remain on Word file and not switch to any other app but only when I release `Alt + Tab` keys. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot is to use the old-style alt-tab switcher, it can be activated by using the plain non-aero UI or using a registry setting as is detailed here: [Getting back the old Alt-Tab windows switching behavior in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/114001/getting-back-the-old-alt-tab-windows-switching-behavior-in-windows-7)

There also seem to be a couple of free alternative switchers: https://alternativeto.net/software/vistaswitcher

However, I have no experience with those, I stayed with the classic theme right up to migrating to Win10.