# How can I completely disable Aero Peek?

Tags: windows-10, aero-peek

I'm looking for a way to completely disable Aero Peek, at least this is what I think this feature is called, in Windows 10. I tried TaskbarThumbsTuner but it didn't do what I was looking for.

When I hover a set of tasks that are combined together and I hover one of the tasks then all the windows other than the one that I hover disappear and only the one that I hover is seen.

I use the computer as the diver of a video projector, and I always have something on the projector. This feature is hiding the window on the projector and the desktop is seen. I always want to keep the window as is, I don't want anything to be faded out and then displayed again - it's annoying for the users.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine, no peek effect.

See the attached screenshots, this is how my desktop looks:

[image: This is how my desktop looks]

I click on the PPT icon in the taskbar and hover the 2nd thumbnail - all the windows are faded out and only the window I hover is viewable

[image: I click on the PPT icon in the taskbar and hover the 2nd thumbnail - all the windows are faded out and only the window I hover is viewable]

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/customization/9205-how-completely-turn-off-aero-peek.html

Comment: I did got through this thread previously - none of the options helped. Even if the thumbnails are not displayed the peek still happens when I hover the task in the combined list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable or delay Alt+Tab Aero Peek effect in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/72946/disable-or-delay-alttab-aero-peek-effect-in-windows-7)

Comment: Alt+Tab does not do Aero Peek - I don't see the problem with Alt+Tab

Comment: Could you please post screenshots instead of photos of your screen? To take screenshots on Windows, you can press the Print Screen key on your keyboard and then paste into Paint by pressing CTRL+V.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if this completely disables Aero Peek but you can try this:

1. Right click on the taskbar and go to Properties.
2. Clear the checkbox for: Use Aero Peek to preview the desktop
3. Search for "Adjust performance and appearance in Windows" with the Start Menu
4. Uncheck the boxes that have to do with Aero Peek or Aero (or just check Adjust for best performance which should completely remove any elements of Aero in Windows)

Additionally: in Personalization, are you using the basic theme instead of the Normal Windows 10 theme? Try **disabling** the Theme service completely and in the "Adjust appearance and performance of Windows".

Comment: The "Use Peek to preview the desktop when you move .." is unchecked and all the check boxes are unchecked in "Visual Effects"  section.

Comment: Try this: Open services.msc and then stop the "Themes" Service. That should stop all theme-related visual effects, including Aero.

Comment: Themes service disables and the peek still happens.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing happening. If the Themes service is disabled, then your theme is reverted to Windows Classic which doesn't support any Aero functionality. Is there any way you could post a picture or short video or your computer in action? I would be able to help you better that way

Comment: I just did post the pictures, before you posted the request. In the 1st picture you can see that the "Themes" service is stopped.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now: Check these settings - in Personalization, are you using the basic theme instead of the Normal Windows 10 theme? It looks like in your pictures you are just using the regular theme. Also, try disabling the Theme service completely and in the "Adjust appearance and performance of Windows".

Comment: OK, it seems that now it seems that it's working as expected :) Thank you InterLinked

Comment: @InterLinked - please add the info about the theme to your answer -- that solved it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to disable Aero Peek:

1. Right-click the Start button.
2. Select **System**.
3. Select **Advanced system settings** on the left side of the window.
4. Under the **Advanced** tab and **Performance** section, select **Settings…**.
5. Under the **Visual Effects** tab, make sure that **Enable Aero Peek** is unchecked. You may need to select **Custom:** before.
6. Select **OK** or **Apply** to confirm your settings.

Comment: This was already off, but i have this annoying peek thing

Answer (score 2):

I found this suggestion of @InterLinked is the only thing that works in windows 10.

> Open services.msc and then stop the "Themes" Service. That should stop
>   all theme-related visual effects, including Aero

Indeed it does! Note that it isn't immediate, first you need to hit alt-tab a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

## **MEGA FIX AERO PEEK WIN7:**

**FIX 1:**

Open `CMD` with Administrator

Execute and wait:

```
net stop uxsms
```

Execute and wait:

```
net stop uxsms
```

**FIX 2:**

Open `REGEDIT`

Navigate to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
```

Create in the DWM, DWORD 32-bit:

Name: `UseMachineCheck` (Set Value ZERO)
Name: `Blur` (Set Value ZERO)
Name: `Animations` (Set Value ZERO)

Open CMD with Administrator

Execute and wait:

```
net stop uxsms
```

Execute and wait:

```
net stop uxsms
```

Restart your system.

*FONT:* [*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz_bignNw_0*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz_bignNw_0)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell way:

```
IF(!(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM -Name EnableAeroPeek -ErrorAction 0)){
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM -Name EnableAeroPeek -PropertyType DWORD -Value 0
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM -Name EnableAeroPeek -Value 0
```

Answer (score -2):

I found an easy way for Windows 10. Press Windows key, type "Performance", then click "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows", then click the radio button "Adjust for best performance", then click "Apply". Done. So whenever I hover over my icons on the task bar, I don't see the annoying Aero Peeks. :)

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Answer (score -3):

Found it! Now I can go to bed.
WINDOWS 10 - remove aero taskbar
Right click on Taskbar --> settings --> colors (or theme and then on the right, next to image there is COLOR section) --> scroll down --> turn THAT OFF! Transparency effect: OFF =) hope it helps!

That above ^ : services.msc doesn't work, at least not for me.