# IE8 tabs are shown as separate windows when switching between windows using Alt+Tab

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

When I open 2 tabs in Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7, they are visible as 2 IE windows when doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I want it to behave more like Chrome or Firefox - when I open 2 tabs in Chrome I can only see one Chrome window when doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I achieve this in IE8?

Comment: I am curious why not switch to IE 9, at least no such problem.

Comment: @HansChen unfortunately this is the company policy

Answer (score 2):

Get all the latest updates from Windows Update (aside from IE9). On a fresh Windows 7 / IE 8 system with all updates, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works as you want it to.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a company owned machine, I cannot run updates. It would be best if I could find a configuration option somewhere in the registry or something?

Comment: There's a way to re-enable the Windows XP-style switcher in the registry. Does this do the trick? http://superuser.com/a/78314/157255